# Ordering by date. Comparator. Java

Tags: java, arguments, comparator

the next snippet taken from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) java tutorial, compares the second argument object to the first one rather than viceversa.
*The method hireDate() returns a Date object signifying the hiring date of that particular employee.

```
import java.util.*;
public class EmpSort {
    static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = 
                                        new Comparator<Employee>() {
            public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                return e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate());
            }
    };
```

Here is the java tutorial explanation:

> Note that the Comparator passes the hire date of its second argument
>   to its first rather than vice versa. The reason is that the employee
>   who was hired most recently is the least senior; sorting in the order
>   of hire date would put the list in reverse seniority order.

Still I do not get why by inverting e1 and e2 in `compareTo` it should solve the issue.

Any further clarification?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The natural order on dates (as defined by `compareTo`) is that the later date is "greater than" the earlier one.  For seniority the person who has been there the longer is more senior, i.e. you want the *earlier* start date to signify greater seniority than the later one.

Since the contract of `Comparator` states that if `compare(a,b) != 0` then `compare(a,b)` and `compare(b,a)` must have opposite sign, you have two choices for how to implement a reverse ordered comparison of `a` and `b` - either return `-(a.compareTo(b))` or `b.compareTo(a)` - they are guaranteed to have the same sign.

They will not necessarily have the same *value*, but the only thing that matters for comparator results is whether they are `>`, `<` or `==` to 0 - while many examples use `-1`, `0` and `+1` any value with the right sign is fine.

Comment: yes but how do you know which one is older in advance? should not it be the same?

Comment: at the end it counts what it's put in by the method user.

Comment: @Rollerball I don't understand what you're asking.  The code snippet you've provided in the question is just a way to define a comparator that can take two employees and tell you which one is more senior by choosing the one with the earlier `hireDate()`, it's not "counting" anything.

Comment: I do not understand why it matters that e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate()) it's different from e1.hireDate().compareTo(e2.hireDate()). I do not know in advance which of the two object is elder or younger (in terms of seniority). I could get a positive or a negative value out of compareTo.

Comment: @Rollerball if you have a list of employees and sorted that list with a comparator that did `e1.hireDate().compareTo(e2.hireDate())` then you'd get them ordered from most senior to least senior (i.e. in _reverse_ order of seniority).  If you sort by `e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate())` you get them ordered from least senior to most senior.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change the sort order then use:

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
```

Don't play with the Comparator.

Comment: This helped reduce my efforts to half.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Comparator's `compare` method expects to return -1, 0 or 1 if `e1<e2`, `e1==e2`, or `e1>e2`. So if the final order you get is just the inverse of desired, simply invert a and b resolves the problem.

Comment: yes but how do you know which one is older in advance? should not it be the same?